# ArrayList and Collection problems

Tags: java, button, collections, arraylist

I hope this makes sense, and that there is a tidier way of programming this.

I have an ArrayList of Buttons and a Collection of Territories, I am trying to figure out how to iterate through the ArrayList and set each label on the buttons to an int value that each Territory contains, then change the colour of the buttons background to correspond to its owner.

The long way is set the label for each button, and then use an if-else to check the owner and set the correct background colour, however, this would cause hundreds of lines of repeated code.

```
btnEgy.setLabel(Territory.EGYPT.units());
    if(Territory.EGYPT.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 1"))
    {
        btnEgy.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if(Territory.EGYPT.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 2"))
    {
        btnEgy.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    else if (Territory.EGYPT.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 3"))
    {
        btnEgy.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (Territory.EGYPT.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 4"))
    {
        btnEgy.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
btnEus.setLabel(Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES.units());
    if(Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 1"))
    {
        btnEus.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if(Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 2"))
    {
        btnEus.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    else if (Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 3"))
    {
        btnEus.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 4"))
    {
        btnEus.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
```

Comment: and your question is....

Comment: @Funtik question is how to avoid repeated code.

Comment: What is `Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES`, `Territory.EGYPT` is it enumeration?

Comment: You shouldn't use the toString() method on Owner to compare for equality.  Something like getOwner().getName() would be more appropriate as toString() has no contract.

Answer (score 3):

```
HashMap<String, Color> playerMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();
playerMap.add("Player 1", Color.BLUE);
playerMap.add("Player 2", Color.RED);
```

then

```
btnEgy.setBackground(playerMap.get(Territory.EGYPT.getOwner().toString()));
```

Comment: This is a bit of a workable "hax" solution if you ask me. It would be much clearer to see what is going on and the entire structure if it took a more OO approach. You can easily just make the Owner here return a color directly.

Comment: That depends, it appears that the territory and it's owner are some sort of domain model, which means a UI property like background colour doesn't belong to it.  The colour mappings is a simple and reasonable solution.

Comment: @Pescis That you could. Good point. However, there are often alternative ways to do things, I still think my solution is simple and reasonable as Robin said.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the same number of buttons and territories,

```
Iterator<Button> itr1 = buttons.iterator();
Iterator<Territory> itr2 = territories.iterator();
while(itr1.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext()) {
    Button button = itr1.next();
    Territory territory = itr2.next();
    // set button data to territory data
}

If the collection sizes don't match then you'll need to figure out if you want to terminate when you reach the end of the shorter collection, or if you want to keep looping through the shorter collection until you reach the end of the longer collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using function in java?

main code

```
setValues(btnEgy,Territory.EGYPT);
setValues(btnEus,Territory.E_UNITEDSTATES);
```

function code

```
 public void setValues(Button btn,Territory t ){
    btn.setLabel(t.units());

    if(t.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 1"))
    {
       btn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if(t.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 2"))
    {
       btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    else if (t.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 3"))
    {
        btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (t.getOwner().toString().equals("Player 4"))
    {
       btn.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a List of Buttons and a List of Territories of equal length where buttons[0] is for territories[0] and so on...

```
final Iterator<Button> buttonI = buttons.iterator();
final Iterator<Territory> territoryI = territories.iterator();
while (territoryI.hasNext() && buttonI.hasNext()) {
    final Button button = buttonI.next();
    final Territory territory = territoryI.next();
    button.setBackground(territory.getOwner().getColor());
    button.setLabel(territory.units());
}
```

Here I have assumed you can add a `getColor()` method to the class returned by `territory.getOwner()`.